# Remapping XF86_Back/Forward to Control/Alt in X

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout

I'd like to rebind the XF86_Back and forward keys in X to control and alt respectively.

However, it seems that running

> xmodmap -e "keycode 167 =Alt_L"
>   xmodmap -e "keycode 166 =Control_L"

isn't giving me the desired behaviour - I cannot type `BACK + a` to get to the start of line in a terminal, for example,even though `xev` is showing them as being correctly rebound.

EDIT:
The output from xev (with my comments as //comments) - alt works, control doesn't

// BACk
KeyPress event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x2bd, subw 0x0, time 3547970265, (983,501), root:(984,516),
    state 0x10, keycode 166 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x2bd, subw 0x0, time 3547970385, (983,501), root:(984,516),
    state 0x10, keycode 166 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

// FORWARD
KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x2bd, subw 0x0, time 3547974553, (983,501), root:(984,516),
    state 0x10, keycode 167 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 64
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x2bd, subw 0x0, time 3547974713, (983,501), root:(984,516),
    state 0x18, keycode 167 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 64
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the Control_L keysym is bound to the "Control" modifier:

```
keycode 166 = Control_L
add Control = Control_L
```

To verify in `xev`, when you release the key, the reported `state` needs to have bit 0x4 set - i.e. if you have NumLock on, when you press the new "Control" key, you should have `state 0x10`, and when you release it, you should get `state 0x14`. Similarly for the new "Alt" key, which should change from `0x10` to `0x18` (also assuming NumLock is active - that's the `0x10` part).

Comment: So, besides it not being loaded (thanks ubuntu), the problem was that I needed `add Control = Control_L`. Cheers